# React Typescript socket.io-client Typescript error on io.connect

Tags: reactjs, typescript, socket.io

I am using React Typescript with socket.io-client 4.0.0 and @types/socket.io-client 3.0.0.
All is good up to a point in the code:

```
socket = io.connect(`ws://${WS_DOMAIN}:${WS_PORT}`, { transports: ["websocket"] });
```

I am getting the following error on io.connect:

```
any
Property 'connect' does not exist on type '{ (opts?: Partial<ManagerOptions &
SocketOptions> | undefined): Socket<DefaultEventsMap, DefaultEventsMap>; (uri: string, 
opts?: Partial<...> | undefined): Socket<...>; (uri: string | Partial<...>, opts?: 
Partial<...> | undefined): Socket<...>; }'.ts(2339)
```

I would like the error to go away but of course, I do not know how to get rid of it. This is the only error I have in my tsx file.

It is worth to mention this is a class-based component. The IO is imported as such:

```
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
```

and type is assigned before initialization of the class:

```
let socket: any;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the documentation I have noticed that the way IO connection is used is as follows:

```
io(`ws://${WS_DOMAIN}:${WS_PORT}`, { transports: ["websocket"] });
```

so without the `io.connect` part

This has also resolved my issue. Hope this helps someone that might encounter similar problem.

Answer (score 5):

I would install "@types/socket.io" and then on client side, import like this:

```
import * as io from "socket.io-client";
const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:4000");
```

It cleared the error for me.

Comment: This answer is deprecated now as the types are bundled with socket.io.

Answer (score 0):

[2022]:In the type script **react** project this might help you. For the latest socket.io-client this is working fine for me.

I have solve this issue by with this following code.

```
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
const ChatRoom =({username,room})=>{
 const socket = io('http://localhost:3001');
 const joinRoom = () => {
    if (username !== "" && room !== "") {
      socket.emit("join_room", room);
     
    }

useEffect(()=>{
    joinRoom();
},[room])
  };


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ChatComponent socket={socket} username={username} room={room} />
    </div>
  );
}
```